# Batch Update to use wildcard directory

Tags: batch-file, directory, wildcard

I am trying to update a batch file I used at an old firm to work at a new firm. I have attached the original batch file. The part I am struggling with is my new firm adds an "_" and the job name after the job number so I don't know how to resolve that. I've been trying for a while reading posts and web pages but just cant get my head around it. The intent of the batch file would be to search all of the text files in a directory and its sub directories for a string, and return a list of which file(s) the string was found in. Here is the original batch file.

```
@echo off

if not exist f:\acad\%2\nul goto error2
if "%1"==""  goto error
if "%2"==""  goto error

echo. *** Search results for all Geodimeter raw data files *** >c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. *** Searching for 5=%1 *** >>c:\dos_survey\null.
FOR %%F IN (f:\acad\%2\*.%2) DO FIND "5=%1" %%F >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. *** Searching for PT%1 *** >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. >>c:\dos_survey\null.
FOR %%F IN (f:\acad\%2\*.%2) DO FIND "PT%1" %%F >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. *** Searching for %1, *** >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. >>c:\dos_survey\null.
FOR %%F IN (f:\acad\%2\*.%2) DO FIND "%1," %%F >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. GPS file search results: >>c:\dos_survey\null.
FOR %%F IN (f:\acad\%2\GPS*.%2) DO FIND "%1," %%F >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo. TFR file search results: >>c:\dos_survey\null.
FOR %%F IN (f:\acad\%2\T*.%2) DO FIND "--%1" %%F >>c:\dos_survey\null.
echo.
CALL LN
REM echo. Type "LN" to view results.
echo.
goto end

:error
echo.
echo. **********************************************************************
echo. ***** USAGE:   FINDPT [point number] [job]                      ******
echo. ***** EXAMPLE: To find point number 1254 in job number 511,     ******
echo. *****          type "FINDPT 1254 511" followed by [RETURN].     ******
echo. **********************************************************************
echo.
goto end

:error2
echo.
echo. Invalid syntax, or directory "%2" does not exist.
goto error

:end
```

Comment: There are some changes you need to implement in your posted script. The first obvious one is simply the order of lines 3,4 & 5, which should be switched to 5, 4, then 3. Then you definitely must change the name of your output file. "Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not".

Answer (score 0):

Before your first `echo` line, insert

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%F IN ('dir /b /ad "f:\acad\%2_*" ') DO set "jobdir=%%F"
```

Then substitute `\%jobdir%\` for `\%2\` in the remainder of the code AND enclose the constructed name in quotes, `"f:\acad%jobdir%*.%2" to ensure that names including spaces will be processed correctly.

The `for` statement will analyse a basic (names-only) directory-list of directories (`/d`) matching `%2_*` and assign the entire name-string to `%%F` and then to `jobdir`. See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation.